# Copying content of a remote file into the local clipboard over PuTTY

Tags: putty, clipboard

I am accessing a Unix system using Putty and need to copy the content of one of the Unix files into my local Windows. How can I do this?

Comment: for a small text file, selected portion of screen is automatically put in windows clipboard. for larger or binary file, you must use winscp/fileezilla.

Answer (score 3):

In order to copy the content of the files from Linux to windows machine. You can use WINSCP. Install WINSCP in windows and use the login credentials of linux and vice versa to transfer the files.